# When sketching the graph of the antiderivative does it matter if I cross the x axis?

Tags: calculus

I am currently doing antiderivatives and I just finished drawing the graph of one, but then I realized that the book had an almost same graph as mine. The only difference between mine and the book's was that mine crossed the x axis less times than the book's..Here is a picture of the sketch.

I don't think it matters though since it should come out the same when you derive it to get f(x) from F(x)... 
The graph labelled 1 is mine and the one with less detail is the book's.

[image]

EDIT: I was given the information that F(0) = 1 as well.

[image]

Comment: What are the actual functions being graphed?

Comment: I'll screen shot it and add it on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question!  No, it doesn't matter.  Remember, all antiderivatives of the same function differ by a constant.  So you could always add or subtract enough to prevent or guarantee crossing the $x$-axis.

*Unless* you are given extra information, like $F(0) = 1$.  Now you're talking about a *specific* function and the graphs would have to match.

The big question is whether $F(3)$ is positive or negative.  By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus
$$
F(3) - F(0) = \int_0^3 f(x)\,dx \implies F(3) = 1 + \int_0^3 f(x)\,dx
$$
It's pretty clear from the picture that $\int_0^3 f(x)\,dx<0$.  Is it less than $-1$?  Equivalently, is the area below the graph on $[0,2]$ at least one more than the area above the graph on $[0,3]$?  That's believable, especially if you assume the scale on the $y$-axis is the same as on the $x$-axis.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of that, but to differ by a constant wouldn't it have to be something along the lines of a shift? The #2 graph (book's answer) started at (0,1) like I did, but after that ti was completely different.

Comment: Well, more accurate to say it doesn't matter assuming the functions differ ONLY by a constant. I don't think the graphs alone are enough to determine that for sure.

Comment: I was givent eh information F(0) = 1... @_@...

Comment: OKay, I just added a picture of the actual question in post, if it does have to be exact, how do I know if I am allowed to cross the x axis?